# What is the BSD equivalent of Linux `netstat -lptun`?

Tags: linux, freebsd, bsd

In Linux, `netstat -lptun` gives a list of servers with the following details:

- protocol
- local and foreign address
- state
- PID and program name

What is the command's equivalent in FreeBSD?

Thanks.

Comment: If you wish to transplant the GNU netstat into BSD, you will probably need to compile it from source.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The command you want is `sockstat`. Use `sockstat -4l` to see just IPv4 listening sockets

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for... thanks heaps

Answer (score 2):

On FreeBSD specifically, [`sockstat(1)`](http://mdoc.su/f/sockstat.1) is indeed useful.

You could also use [`fstat(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/fstat.1) on not just FreeBSD, but all modern BSD systems apart from OS X, although I guess `fstat` will only report presently open sockets each process may have, not the already closed ones recently.  E.g., to omit non-internet files, try `fstat | fgrep -e internet -e USER`.

See also [How to list open files on a UNIX system.](http://tu.cnst.su/post/16265257764/how-to-list-open-files-on-a-unix-system)

Answer (score -1):

netBSD also have netstat program alongside their repository since netBSD 2.0, if on your machine doesn't have, you can install it, so you can use netstat on netBSD. here the guide http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=1&page=netstat&manpath=NetBSD-2.0

Comment: Thank you, but BSD netstat is different from GNU netstat.